# How Can I Exclude specific Tag(<br>) from Response.xpath?

Tags: python, dom, xpath, extract

Here is some sample source html below, I want to get a string (or list)
result.

```
<font class="news">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <a href="../1.jpg" target="_blank" onfocus='this.blur()'>
                    <img src="../pic1/small_16239927831.jpg" width="300" >
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    AAA<br><br>
    BBB<br><br>
    CCC<br>
</font>
```

I can get some result with this

```
response.xpath('//font[@class="body_news"]/text()')
```

or

```
response.xpath('//font[@class="body_news"]/text()').extract()
```

However, the result has many `\n` or `\n\t` , I just want to get `"AAA BBB CCC"` or `['AAA','BBB','CCC']` .

I also used `normalize-space()`, but does not work. How can I exclude those newlines or tabs?

> ```
> ['AAA', '\n\t\t', '\n\n\t\t', 'BBB', '\n\t\t', 'CCC', '\n\t' ]
> ```

Comment: Your question is poorly formatted. The normalize-space should do the job. Could you share the source html?

Answer (score 0):

This XPath:

```
normalize-space(//font[@class='news'])
```

gives this result:

```
AAA BBB CCC
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?